# Using python and selenium to get elemnts in <div> to a list or dataframe

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a table created using 'div' elements, which has dynamic content based on the choice and also the data to be displayed that are generated with javascript. Html structure is like this:

```html
<div class="container-jKD0Exn-">
<div class="shrinkShadowPosition-OFmmj-q_">
<div class="shrinkShadowWrap-OFmmj-q_">
<div class="shrinkShadow-OFmmj-q_">
</div></div></div>
<div class="titleWrap-jKD0Exn-" style="box-shadow:none">
<div class="offsetPadding-jKD0Exn-" style="width:0"></div>
<span class="title-jKD0Exn- apply-overflow-tooltip">Total common shares outstanding</span></div>
<div class="filling-jKD0Exn-"></div>
<div class="values-jKD0Exn- values-ZmRZjHnV">
<div class="value-25PNPwRV">
<div class="wrap-25PNPwRV">
<div>‪22.32B‬</div>
</div></div>
<div class="value-25PNPwRV">
<div class="wrap-25PNPwRV">
<div>‪21.34B‬</div>
</div></div>
<div class="value-25PNPwRV">
<div class="wrap-25PNPwRV"><div>‪20.50B‬</div>
</div></div>
```

Using below python code, result is like this:
Total common shares outstanding‪22.32B‬‪21.34B‬‪20.50B‬‪19.02B‬‪17.77B‬‪16.98B‬‪16.43B‬‪16.33B‬
Instead I would it in a list or in a dtaframe like this:

`['Total common shares outstanding‪',22.32,21.34,‬‪20.50B‬,19.02,17.77,‬‪16.98B‬,16.43,‬‪16.33,]`

Python code I'm using to scrape data is this one:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import requests, bs4
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url ='https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/financials-statistics-and-ratios/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
#print(html)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for title in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "container-jKD0Exn-"}):
     print(title.text+'\n')
```

Is there any way in selenium or beautifulsoap to get a list like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one approach, if there is no api, what you should prefer to use, you can go with `BeautifulSoup` and `stripped_strings`:

```
data = []
for title in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "container-jKD0Exn-"}):
     data.append(list(title.stripped_strings))

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output DataFrame:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key stats |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Total common shares outstanding | ‪22.32B‬ | ‪21.34B‬ | ‪20.50B‬ | ‪19.02B‬ | ‪17.77B‬ | ‪16.98B‬ | ‪16.43B‬ | ‪16.33B‬ |
| Float shares outstanding | ‪22.29B‬ | ‪21.32B‬ | ‪20.48B‬ | ‪18.99B‬ | ‪17.75B‬ | ‪16.96B‬ | ‪16.41B‬ | ‪16.32B‬ |
| Number of employees | ‪110.00K‬ | ‪116.00K‬ | ‪123.00K‬ | ‪132.00K‬ | ‪137.00K‬ | ‪147.00K‬ | ‪154.00K‬ | — |
| Number of shareholders | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | ‪23.50K‬ | — |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to print the desired texts you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/financials-statistics-and-ratios/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accept']"))).click()
  df = pd.DataFrame([my_elem.text.replace('\u202a', ' ').replace('\u202c', ' ') for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Total common shares outstanding']//following::div[2]//div[starts-with(@class, 'wrap')]/div")))], columns = ['Total common shares outstanding'])
  print(df)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
        Total common shares outstanding
  0                         22.32B
  1                         21.34B
  2                         20.50B
  3                         19.02B
  4                         17.77B
  5                         16.98B
  6                         16.43B
  7                         16.33B
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```